# Metamask removed the cancel button for a transaction but ive waited for like a week and the transaction is not done

Tags: metamask

So i have a transaction running on the eth mainnet which is pending but it has been over 1 week now and i have sped up the transaction many times. Now, i dont even have the ability to cancel the transaction. How do i end this transaction as im unable to do anything else on the eth mainnet without the transactions becoming stuck.